# How to save changes in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, savestate

I'm new in android development so I don't have all the basics yet.
I'm stuck with my problem since a few days. 
 
My problem is as follows:
I got a recyclerview with some items inside. I created a button to add new item in the list. Adding function works fine, I can see any new item, but if I swipe to the third fragment (I got 3 fragments in my app, and recyclerView is on the left one) or if I simply kill my app and relaunch it, every new items are destroyed.
So basically I don't know how to really save that kind of thing in android app. I need your help to show me the way.
Here is my code:

Fragment with recyclerview

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment  {

//matchselector reclycler view
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SnapRecyclerAdapter adapter;
// add
private View addMatch;
private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
private EditText team1_add;
private View view;
private boolean add = false;
private int edit_position;
private Item newitem;


public static CameraFragment create() {
    return new CameraFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

    initDialog();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //match selector vertical recycler view
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    addMatch = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.add_match);


    /**
     * Center snapping
     */
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    final CustomLinearLayoutManager mCustomLinearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mCustomLinearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter = new SnapRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    MatchList();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //Button addmatch click
    addMatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.add_match:
                removeView();
                add = true;
                alertDialog.setTitle("Ajout");
                team1_add.setText("");
                alertDialog.show();
                break;
        }
    }
    });

}

// dialog ajout
private void initDialog(){
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_addmatch,null);
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ajouter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(add){
                add =false;
                newitem = new Item(5, team1_add.getText().toString(), "0", "0","0" , "0" ,   R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge);
                adapter.addItem(newitem);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                items.set(edit_position, newitem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
    team1_add = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.team1_add);
}


private void removeView(){
    if(view.getParent()!=null) {
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    }
}


public void MatchList() {
    items.add(new Item(1, "a", "b", "c","d" , "12:30" ,   R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    items.add(new Item(4, "a", "b", "c","d" , "12:30" ,  R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    items.add(new Item(2, "a", "b", "c",  "d" , "12:30" , R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    items.add(new Item(3, "a", "b", "c","d" , "12:30" ,  R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

SnapRecyclerAdapter:

```
public class SnapRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SnapRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;

public SnapRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(item);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);

    holder.Logoteam1.setImageResource(item.getLogoteam1());
    holder.Logoteam2.setImageResource(item.getLogoteam2());
    holder.team1.setText(item.getTeam1());
    holder.team2.setText(item.getTeam2());
    holder.categorie.setText(item.getCategorie());
    holder.location.setText(item.getLocation());
    holder.date.setText(item.getDate());


}

public void addItem(Item newitem) {
    items.add(newitem);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void removeItem(int position) {
    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView Logoteam1;
    private ImageView Logoteam2;
    private TextView team1;
    private TextView team2;
    private TextView categorie;
    private TextView location;
    private TextView date;

    private RecyclerViewHolder(final View v) {
        super(v);

        Logoteam1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Logoteam1);
        Logoteam2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Logoteam2);
        team1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team1);
        team2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team2);
        categorie = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categorie);
        location = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I do not follow, how do you want them to be saved after onDestroy?. Do you understand that these objects are saved in memory, right?. Correct me if I am wrong, but I do not see any persistent way of saving the data(db, sharedprefs, storage, etc).

Comment: I think you need to persist your data somehow. You have several options - shared preferences, a file on the file system and some database. Explaining them would be quite a long task so I'd recommend you to read the Data Storage Guide - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects to the list in the Recycleview are created whenever that specific fragment is loaded. So everytime you kill the application or move to your third fragment , the first fragment is reloaded and the object is created again containing only the default values that you have put. Adding to the list is valid only till that object remains in memory , else it is destroyed. Based on your requirement you can go for any storage medium such as Sharedpreferences(Using Serailization) or even sqlite(though not much required for small tasks) .

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to add an item to the top of the recycler view is the following :

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment  {

//matchselector reclycler view
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SnapRecyclerAdapter adapter;
// add
private View addMatch;
private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
private EditText team1_add;
private View view;
private boolean add = false;
private int edit_position;
private Item newitem;


public static CameraFragment create() {
    return new CameraFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

    initDialog();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //match selector vertical recycler view
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    addMatch = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.add_match);


    /**
     * Center snapping
     */
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    final CustomLinearLayoutManager mCustomLinearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mCustomLinearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter = new SnapRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    MatchList();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //Button addmatch click
    addMatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.add_match:
        int position = 0

               newitem = new Item(5, team1_add.getText().toString(), "0", "0","0" , "0" ,   R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge);
                items.add(position,"" + newitem)
 adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
               // removeView();
              //  add = true;
              //  alertDialog.setTitle("Ajout");
              //  team1_add.setText("");
              //  alertDialog.show();
                break;
        }
    }
    });

}

// dialog ajout
private void initDialog(){
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout_addmatch,null);
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ajouter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(add){
                add =false;
                newitem = new Item(5, team1_add.getText().toString(), "0", "0","0" , "0" ,   R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge);
                adapter.addItem(newitem);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                items.set(edit_position, newitem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
    team1_add = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.team1_add);
}


private void removeView(){
    if(view.getParent()!=null) {
        ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    }
}


public void MatchList() {
    items.add(new Item(1, "a", "b", "c","d" , "12:30" ,   R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    items.add(new Item(4, "a", "b", "c","d" , "12:30" ,  R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    items.add(new Item(2, "a", "b", "c",  "d" , "12:30" , R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    items.add(new Item(3, "a", "b", "c","d" , "12:30" ,  R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge, R.mipmap.ic_blasonvierge));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```